# Using Jquery with wordpress theme?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am currently using wordpress 3.4.1
I would like to embedd jquery in my own wordpress theme but i am unable to do it. Tried max possible solutions available on net but still not convincingly able to implement it. Please help with the simple example!!

Comment: Are you saying you created your own theme but don't know how to include a script ?

Comment: yes !! that's what m tryin to do !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For best compatibility, use the version of jQuery that WordPress comes with (loading a specific version of jQuery may break your plugins in the future):

Add to function.php:

```
function insert_jquery(){
   wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
}
add_filter('wp_head','insert_jquery');
```

Or if you want to load it from Google CDN:

```
function my_scripts_method() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}    

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method');
```

Read more here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

The following links can also be used:

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js - Most recent version

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js - latest within ver 1.x family

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js - latest within ver 1.7.x family

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js - latest within ver 1.8.x family

Answer (score 0):

try Below code.

below code added your function.php in your theme

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_myJquery');

function add_myJquery()
{
?>
    <script src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/js/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {

            //write your jquery code Here.
        });

    </script>
<?    
}
```

Or

below code added in between html head tag in your theme header.php file

```
<script src="<?php bloginfo( 'template_url' ); ?>/js/jquery-latest.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: when i apply a jquery with toggle funtion..it works but the thing is it hides the button itself.

Comment: i've placed the button in my wordpress page and applied toggle effect on all <p> elements but why the buttons gets hidden??